# Formatting/Storing Batch "wmic idecontroller" output

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am relatively new to batch scripting particularly in a windows environment. I would like to be able to gather the HDD information about a specific machine through the following command:

```
wmic idecontroller
```

However when I run that command, the output that I recieve looks like this:

```
Availability  Caption                                                                          ConfigManagerErrorCode  ConfigManagerUserConfig  CreationClassName    Description                                                                      DeviceID                                                      ErrorCleared  ErrorDescription  InstallDate  LastErrorCode  Manufacturer                          MaxNumberControlled  Name                                                                             PNPDeviceID                                                   PowerManagementCapabilities  PowerManagementSupported  ProtocolSupported  Status  StatusInfo  SystemCreationClassName  SystemName    TimeOfLastReset  
          ATA Channel 0                                                                    0                       FALSE                    Win32_IDEController  IDE Channel                                                                      PCIIDE\IDECHANNEL\4&160FD31B&0&0                                                                                          (Standard IDE ATA/ATAPI controllers)                       ATA Channel 0                                                                    PCIIDE\IDECHANNEL\4&160FD31B&0&0                                                                                     37                 OK                  Win32_ComputerSystem     TEST                   
          ATA Channel 3                                                                    0                       FALSE                    Win32_IDEController  IDE Channel                                                                      PCIIDE\IDECHANNEL\4&160FD31B&0&3                                                                                          (Standard IDE ATA/ATAPI controllers)                       ATA Channel 3                                                                    PCIIDE\IDECHANNEL\4&160FD31B&0&3                                                                                     37                 OK                  Win32_ComputerSystem     TEST                   
          ATA Channel 4                                                                    0                       FALSE                    Win32_IDEController  IDE Channel                                                                      PCIIDE\IDECHANNEL\4&160FD31B&0&4                                                                                          (Standard IDE ATA/ATAPI controllers)                       ATA Channel 4                                                                    PCIIDE\IDECHANNEL\4&160FD31B&0&4                                                                                     37                 OK                  Win32_ComputerSystem     TEST                   
          ATA Channel 5                                                                    0                       FALSE                    Win32_IDEController  IDE Channel                                                                      PCIIDE\IDECHANNEL\4&160FD31B&0&5                                                                                          (Standard IDE ATA/ATAPI controllers)                       ATA Channel 5                                                                    PCIIDE\IDECHANNEL\4&160FD31B&0&5                                                                                     37                 OK                  Win32_ComputerSystem     TEST                   
          Intel(R) 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 Port SATA AHCI Controller - 1C03  0                       FALSE                    Win32_IDEController  Intel(R) 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 Port SATA AHCI Controller - 1C03  PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1C03&SUBSYS_04A31028&REV_04\3&11583659&0&FA                                                              Intel                                                      Intel(R) 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 Port SATA AHCI Controller - 1C03  PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1C03&SUBSYS_04A31028&REV_04\3&11583659&0&FA                                                         37                 OK                  Win32_ComputerSystem     TEST
```

If I wanted to only gather information from a specific column, and store each of those strings into a variable, what would be the best method? For example, if I wanted to store all of the fields under "Description" to an array of strings!

Comment: well, first, you use a where clause to `WMIC` to filter out the columns you want. Then, you use a `FOR` loop to put those columns into variables. Edit your post with specifics and I or someone else will show you how to do it. WMIC filtering in a `FOR` loop can get a little tricky your first time trying it. Consider SO your Excedrin ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here you go. Batch doesn't have arrays per se, but you can duplicate an array like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set cnt=0
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic idecontroller get description /value^| Find "="') do (
  set /a cnt+=1
  set Ide[!cnt!]=%%a
)

for /L %%a in (1,1,%cnt%) do echo !Ide[%%a]!
```

Comment: I found this very useful and used the "array" to implement subroutines "add_error" and "display_errors" to summarize all that went wrong during a potentially long and verbose execution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SET "columnname=%~1"
IF NOT DEFINED columnname ECHO require column name as parameter&GOTO :EOF 

:: make a tempfile
:maketemp
SET "tempfile=%temp%\%random%"
IF EXIST "%tempfile%*" (GOTO maketemp) ELSE (ECHO.>"%tempfile%a")
:: remove variables starting $
FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set $ 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="

wmic idecontroller |more>q22454696.txt
:: SET header=first line
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q22454696.txt) DO SET "header=%%a"&GOTO haveheader
:haveheader
:: calculate column positions
::
:: header length
>"%tempfile%a" (ECHO(%header%)&FOR %%a IN ("%tempfile%a") DO SET /a hlength=%%~za - 2
:: find part following columnname
SET "rest=!header:*%columnname%=!"
:: and part before columnname
SET "before=!header:%columnname%%rest%=!"
>"%tempfile%a" (ECHO(%before%)&FOR %%a IN ("%tempfile%a") DO SET /a blength=%%~za - 2
:: allow for part-of-headername. "rest" may contain remainderofcolumnname-spaces-nextcolumnname
SET /a rlength=0
:restlpc
IF NOT DEFINED rest GOTO havecw
IF NOT "%rest:~0,1%"==" " SET "rest=%rest:~1%"&GOTO restlpc
:restlps
IF NOT DEFINED rest GOTO havecw
IF "%rest:~0,1%"==" " SET "rest=%rest:~1%"&GOTO restlps
>"%tempfile%a" (ECHO(%rest%)&FOR %%a IN ("%tempfile%a") DO SET /a rlength=%%~za - 2
:: Now have column-width data
:havecw
SET /a cwidth=hlength - blength - rlength
REM ECHO header has length %hlength%
REM ECHO %columnname% is AT column %blength%
REM ECHO %columnname% has width %cwidth%

FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN ('findstr /n /r "$" q22454696.txt') DO (
 SET "line=%%b"
 IF "%%b"=="" GOTO done 
 SET "$%%a=!line:~%blength%,%cwidth%!"
)

:done
ECHO resultant array:
SET $
DEL ""%tempfile%a*"

GOTO :EOF
```

There's a couple of problems with `WMIC`. First is that the output is unicode and second is that the column-widths are chosen to fit the data.

So - run the above batch with a parameter. Parameter can be the entire column-header, "quoted if it contains spaces" or a unique partial-startingstring (like `Ca` for Caption).

First it creates the file as specified (name unimportant) but first it's filtered by `MORE` to de-unicode it.

Next, a few gymnastics to locate and calculate the column location and width, using a tempfile.

Then use the results of the calculation to set variables `$1`..`$whatever` containing the required column.

Add a `skip=1` before the `tokens=1` in the final `for /f` if you don't want the column name as part of the array.